# Vuex Axios CORS Block Acess-control-allow-origin

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors, axios, vuex

This is the error:

[image]

So, I make sure my backend API sends the `acess-control-allow-origin` header:

[image: uex]

This my `axios` code:

```js
     loadTopSales ({ commit }) {
       axios
         .get('http://tms.test/api/top-sales', {
           headers: {
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
             Accept: 'application/json',
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.token,
             withCredentials: true
           }
         })
         .then(items => {
           commit('SET_TOP_SALES', items)
           console.log(items)
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
         })
     }
```

Please, help me. I've tried every question in stackoverflow

Check `curl -v -x options`

[image]

My backend set header

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'PUT,POST,GET,OPTIONS,ORIGIN',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin,X-Auth-Token',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value){
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

[image]

This my answer I config CORS in iis

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the API doesn't handle [CORS preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). It should return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for `OPTIONS` method as well (alongside `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) with `204 No Content`.

You can check it with `curl -v -X OPTIONS http://tms.test/api/top-sale`.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see, the desired headers are not present.

Comment: Wrapping up: it's not your frontend code's fault, this should be addressed server-side.

Comment: I read CORS preflight requests already, but i don't understand. `Acess-control-allow-origin:'*'` Isn't it enough?

Comment: I set my backend ` return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,GET,OPTIONS,ORIGIN')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Accept,Authorization,Content-Type,Origin,X-Auth-Token');`

Comment: When you hit your API with a `GET` HTTP method the desired headers are set. The problem is when you hit it with `OPTIONS` method. As you can see it at the response to `curl -X OPTIONS` the headers are not present there. Could you please provide a code snippet of your server side routing in your question?

Comment: (I guess your request reaches the backend code you provided on `GET` method, but it doesn't reach it on `OPTIONS` method)

Comment: Now I'm looking for answers for my backend. Thank you. I'm don't understand it but, i will try quick get it.

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to open a discussion in chat if you need any help backend side.

Comment: I use extension chrome cors * and it works! , So I think the problem as my host. After Axios hit option, I didn't respond to the permission Access-control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Yes the problem is with the API you use. I'm happy you got it working locally with a chrome extension. Let me note that it might not work for people who don't use this extension in production (if there is a misconfiguration there as well).

Comment: My answer is config web.config on host iis and update to questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding proxy for your API with http-proxy-middleware. Note that this will only work for local development only.

You'll get the user guide to use http-proxy-middleware [here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware).

For vueJS specific usage, you can try https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-cli-3-how-to-properly-use-http-proxy-middleware/33723

Comment: If I solve these problems on the local Then will I find it online or not?

Comment: You might've. Usually, for production, we use NGINX Reverse Proxy to proxy our requests.

Comment: You will face the same problems in production. These dev proxies set the desired headers for you if your backend doesn't handle it properly locally, but they won't be present in production.